# Why my solo chain block time is 12 seconds when set to 6?

Tags: substrate-node-template, block-production, substrate-block-time

I have an my own Substrate node (not a parachain, based on the template-node, so Aura consensus is used) and I changed the block time to 6 seconds in the `runtime/src/lib.rs` by setting

```rust
pub const MILLISECS_PER_BLOCK: u64 = 6000;
```

Though, when running the node locally with --dev configuration, it takes 12 seconds to produce blocks:

```bash
2022-09-01 12:50:36.010  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship:  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x7b2d27b8c9d1bacda74bf281bcf1f3fa6fdc9e017490860e55356b695aec9d4d    
2022-09-01 12:50:36.029 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker runtime::system: [1] length: 11 (normal 0%, op: 0%, mandatory 0%) / normal weight: 0 (0%) / op weight 0 (0%) / mandatory weight 5921651000 (0%)    
2022-09-01 12:50:36.030  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship:  Prepared block for proposing at 1 (3 ms) [hash: 0x017f1e5a02dcccb639a13c5fb9e5c5844b4efdfc596613db9da255000b89e414; parent_hash: 0x7b2d…9d4d; extrinsics (1): [0x7932…5556]]    
2022-09-01 12:50:36.031  INFO tokio-runtime-worker aura:  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 1. Hash now 0xdd564786a31bceefd7b4468173234870866615cd9433b438e84214e9debb9a18, previously 0x017f1e5a02dcccb639a13c5fb9e5c5844b4efdfc596613db9da255000b89e414.    
2022-09-01 12:50:36.032  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate: ✨ Imported #1 (0xdd56…9a18)    
2022-09-01 12:50:39.100  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (0 peers), best: #1 (0xdd56…9a18), finalized #0 (0x7b2d…9d4d), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-09-01 12:50:44.101  INFO tokio-runtime-worker substrate:  Idle (0 peers), best: #1 (0xdd56…9a18), finalized #0 (0x7b2d…9d4d), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2022-09-01 12:50:48.001  INFO tokio-runtime-worker sc_basic_authorship::basic_authorship:  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0xdd564786a31bceefd7b4468173234870866615cd9433b438e84214e9debb9a18
```

Why is it taking 12 seconds to produce blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your Aura `chain_spec.rs` have 2 validators in it? Aura is a round-robin based protocol, if you have more than 1 validator, it will expect another block to be made in order of the list of authorities of your chain. Therefore, it might be the case that `Bob` fails to make a block after 6 seconds and loses his turn (since an extra 6 seconds are given to buffer the possibility that `Bob` is slow).

Comment: Excellent! Yes, the chain spec in dev mode has two validators in it. I just removed Bob and it is now 6 seconds. Thank you so much ! I need to study more in depth this part.

Comment: Just for reference to other people who may have this same question, I searched and found that Drew's answer is also explained in the OpenEthereum documentation about Aura: https://openethereum.github.io/Validator-Set-Tutorial-4#title-visualize-misbehaviors .