# Blocktime double than expected (Standalone network)

Tags: substrate-node-template, networking, block-production, substrate-block-time

We are currently running a standalone network, with the blocktime set to 6000ms, but we are seeing fluctuating values as below[image: blocktimes]

As you can see, there is no real relation between blocksizes or extrinsics, wondering what else could be causing issues here and how we can improve this setup.

Currently running a 5 node setup (all validators) in the same region.
Using polkadot-v0.9.30

Comment: Are you using Aura?

Comment: This post may be relevant:
- https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4558/why-my-solo-chain-block-time-is-12-seconds-when-set-to-6

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that two of the validator nodes did not have the aura keys inserted, hence when the chance came to these validators the blocks were skipped. Fixed by adding missing aura keys to the validators, now all validators are authoring blocks and everything works as expected.